# Find application name

Tags: software-center, uninstall, unity-dash

I'm looking for a way to find e.g. the command name for an application that does appear in the dash.

More specifically: I installed the game Costume Quest (from the Double Fine Humble Bundle), and more recently wanted to uninstall it. So I uninstalled it through the Software Center. However, the application still runs, even though the Software Center tells me it's not there.

So I wanted to uninstall it through the command line, but I don't know the package name, or command name. It appears through the dash when I search "Costume Quest", it will run when I click the icon in the dash, but I can't seem to find any file or folder that may give me a hint for the command/package name.

I'm running 13.04, will say more about the hardware if it turns out to be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typed

```
dpkg -l | grep costume
```

which returned

```
ii  costume-quest       0~20130507-0ubuntu1      i386       Halloween adventure [...]
```

and removed it using

```
apt-get purge costume-quest
```

(note that 
    costume-quest
returned an "unknown command" message)

Answer (score 1):

I have not understood very well because my english is not so good but, you should enter the command:

```
top
```

to see the process that are running.

You should see the process's game on the first top lines. And you should see its name in the last column.

After that you should enter:

```
killall <processname>
```

then something like:

```
dpkg -l | grep game
```

to see all the games installed, then search for your game's name package
then try to uninstall it:

```
apt-get purge <game_name_pkg>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However:

- when Costume Quest is running, I can't access a terminal. The "Windows button" doesn't respond, neither does alt+F2, so I can't enter the "top" command.

- the other suggestion just gives me the preinstalled games (minesweeper, sudoku, etc.) not the ones I installed.

Any other suggestion?
Thanks again.